# Grails - validation of incoming data and the persistent instance

Tags: grails

In reading "The Definitive Guide To Grails 2", I am trying to understand the grails validation mechanism. The book states that if a type error occurs during validation then:

> Grails automatically sets the persistent instance to read-only so it
>   cannot persist unless you yourself explicitly make it persist...

What is this persistent instance? Is it the domain object instance that I might be about to try to save to persistent storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the domain object instance that I might be about to try to save
>   to persistent storage?

Yes.